# How to convert unicode from html to regular words

Tags: c#, html, unicode, webclient

```
htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http: //abc.com");
```

When executed, the html has unicode characters such as 来这. How can I convert it correctly and then display in a textbox?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx

Comment: Why don't you just give us the real page so that we can see the actual characters?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
TextBox1.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(client.DownloadString("http://abc.com"));
```

Comment: I don't think that will fix the problem. If the HTML contains that character escape, then displaying the HTML in a text box will show the escape. Something will have to interpret that string and convert the character escape to a real character.

Comment: @JimMischel I changed the code to something that I think might work. Sorry I did not say it before.

Comment: Yeah. I saw and upvoted.